# Как переопределить свойство Size

Tags: c#

Как переопределить свойство Size в DataGridView.Rows[0].HedCell.Size
Оно установлено только на чтение, а мне нужно сделать запись

Comment: Никак. Ищите другой путь.

Comment: На то он и readOnly чтобы вы его не трогали.

Comment: А я думал что можно переопределить. Как мне тогда сузить эту колонку?

Comment: @VladD А рефлекшн - это другой путь?)

Comment: @SVD102 а вы уверены, что вам это нужно? Мне кажется вы решаете свою проблему не правильно. Само ваше желание - порочно, т.к. породить нестандартное, причем не очевидное поведение, которое в будущем можно привести к багам, которые будет крайне сложно отловить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Не, это вообще не путь. Ну установите вы новое значение в поле, но от этого реальный размер же не поменяется. Код-то не предполагает, что кто-то поменяет это значение, и не обязан его оттуда перечитывать. Хуже того, у свойства может вовсе не быть сеттера.

Answer (score 3):

Cell -- это отдельная ячейка, а вам похоже хочется управлять шириной колонки.
Смотрите DataGridView.Columns, берите нужную колонку и ставьте DataGridViewColumn.Width.